# C# Declare a OpenFileDialog inside a property

Tags: c#, properties, dialog, openfiledialog

I'm about to create a custom control , and want to use the OpenFileDialog inside a property. it works fine but everytime I compile the project the dialog opens , but I want to open it whenever I changed the property, here is the code I'm using :

```
private string _customproperty;
 public string stringpro
        {
            get
            {
                return _customproperty;
            }
            set
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "1":
                        _customproperty = "1";
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        using (OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog())
                        {
                            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            {
                                _customproperty = IO.File.ReadAllText(openFile.FileName);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

or is there any better way to doing that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about what happens if they hit `Cancel`?

Comment: well it not the case I can go with the `esle` statement in that case users hit cancel, I want to avoid execute this dialog while compiling.

Comment: "or is there any better way to doing that" for sure there is. This is very, very bad idea. But it's difficult to present a better one if we don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik, I just fixed it by changing the way of declaring and using  [UITypeEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.